# Creating new raster with minimum (or maximum) value betwen two rasters in ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, spatial-analyst, raster-calculator

I am using ArcMap 10.3.

I have two temperature rasters from two months. I need to create a new raster from these, but the new raster should have in each cell the maximun value betwen the initial raster.
Example.

```
Raster 1     Raster 2       Output I need
15             18                  18
19             11                  19
```

Answer (score 2):

If you have access to a Spatial Analyst extension, you can use [Cell Statistics](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/spatial-analyst-toolbox/cell-statistics.htm) (it's in the Local toolbox in Spatial Analyst Tools).  You can add all of the rasters you want to compare and select the statistic type to be output.